# Удаление элемента по индексу в valarray

Tags: c++, массивы, stl, динамические-массивы, containers

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-нибудь реализовать удаление элемента по индексу с контейнера valarray?

Answer (score 0):

Никак, `std::valarray` не предназначен для этого. Если очень хочется, можно создавать новый без нужного элемента.